# Appending a table in jquery in MVC with colspan and rowspan

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am stuck ... I need help. I have a table which is divided into col span. This is my table
[Html table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZABQ.png)

Now I am appending data in jquery after parsing json. My data is that I have a parent row and under that I have to place child rows. For example if there is a parent row beside that I can have multiple child rows.

[My table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCtuY.png)

Now data with SR.No is parent and underneath is child. I want the child data to append beside the parent just like the table. Please help

[Jquery TO append data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsvNM.png)

Comment: please provide codes not images.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please do not use code in an image! See How to Ask and take the tour. More links why code as image are bad https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode / https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7571526

Comment: please create a code snippet or jsfiddle link. thanks